# How to store geocodes in Mongoid array with gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, gmaps4rails

I am able to use the basic map display capabilities in gmaps4rails with mongoid, which is great, but Im falling short with more advanced features.  I think I am missing some basics and looking for guidance. 
I am able to get the basic geocoding to work with fields named :latitude :longitude and :gmaps but when I try to use an array, as suggested by the readme, I am getting nowhere.  I've read the Mongoid tips in the wiki to no avail.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Update;
Since Ive gotten no responses, here is some code examples,

The Model

working;

```
class Account
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Gmaps4rails::ActsAsGmappable
  acts_as_gmappable

  field :account_no
  field :owner_name
  field :address
  field :latitude,  :type => Float
  field :longitude, :type => Float
  field :gmaps,     :type => Boolean

  def gmaps4rails_address
    "#{self.address}"
  end

end
```

Not working

```
 class Account
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Gmaps4rails::ActsAsGmappable
  acts_as_gmappable :position => :location

  field :account_no
  field :owner_name
  field :address
  field :location, :type => Array

  def gmaps4rails_address
  "#{self.address}"
  end

end
```

Based on the code snippets in the gmaps4rails readme this should work to geocode the address into the location array but I get this error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `gmaps' for #<Account:0x007fc47d051ba0>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [here](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Model-Customization), `gmaps` is a boolean which purpose is to prevent multiple geocoding of the same address.

So the field is necessary, unless you tell it explicitly (see same doc)

Comment: I ended up using the geocoder gem which I saw you recommended somewhere.

Comment: Good choice: it's really dedicated to geocoding where gmaps4rails is meant to display stuff